# How can I get battery status info outside of both an activity and service?

Tags: android, battery

I have a class that extends Thread and it's instantiated in my Application class. It's purpose is to monitor various things about the operating system and then build a JSON object of monitored values and send them to a server every 20 seconds or so... one of the bits of data I'm supposed to collect is battery level information. I've only seen [examples](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) on how to do this from within an activity or service. Is there any way I can get this information from outside of an activity and service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a huge battery drain.

The [Battery Manager](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) will let you query for charging status, but you still need a context.  Since you're instantiating this in the Application class, that works out for you.

Edit: just noticed that you'd already read the guide. Look at [this section](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#DetermineChargeState), and remember that the application itself is a valid context:

```
    final IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
```

Comment: Battery drain isn't a problem as these devices will be on kiosks and should be plugged in at all times... we're monitoring them for being unplugged and/or power outages. In your example, how do I get the level from the application to the thread every 20 seconds?

Comment: Pass the thread the battery status Intent when you construct the thread, and query it on whatever interval you please.

Comment: Got it... figured that out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Alternatively: use a Timer. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html